# How can I adjust this div in to foreach loop?

Tags: php, html, foreach

Attributes are (crop_name, crop_img, crop-detail) and I want to show attribute value in this dive (crop_img) inside the `<img>` tag, (crop_name) inside the `<span>` tag and (crop_detail) inside the `<em>` tag.

```
<?php 
  foreach($records as $r) {    }?>

  <div class="cols">
  <figure class="pad_bot2 pad_top1"><img src="" alt="" width="200px" height="211px"></figure>
      <p class="pad_bot2"> <span class="font1 color2"></span><br>
        <em></em><br>
        <a href="#" class="link1">Read More</a> 
      </p>
      </div>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for.  Where do you want these attribute values to appear? As attributes within the div tag?

Answer (score 0):

PHP tags can be directly embedded into HTML tags. You can use like this.

```
<?php 
foreach($records as $r) { ?>    
  <div class="cols">
  <figure class="pad_bot2 pad_top1"><img src="" alt="" width="200px" height="211px"></figure>
      <p class="pad_bot2"> <span class="font1 color2"></span><br>
        <em></em><br>
        <a href="#" class="link1">Read More</a> 
      </p>
  </div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add html inside of foreach body. Try this code. If you need any more help please let me know.

if you are receiving array in $records then use

```
<?php echo $r['index']; ?>
```

if receiving object then use

```
<?php echo $r->index; ?>
```

Below is complete code as you want.

```
<?php foreach($records as $r) {  ?>
  <div class="cols">
  <figure class="pad_bot2 pad_top1"><img src="" alt="" width="200px" height="211px"></figure>
      <p class="pad_bot2"> <span class="font1 color2"></span><br>
        <em></em><br>
        <a href="#" class="link1">Read More</a> 
      </p>
</div>

<?   } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the HTML like below and update value to each markup like for image src=`<?php echo $r->crop_img; ?>`

```
<?php foreach($records as $r) { ?>    
  <div class="cols">
      <figure class="pad_bot2 pad_top1"><img src="<?php echo $r->crop_img; ?>" alt="" width="200px" height="211px"></figure>
      <p class="pad_bot2"> <span class="font1 color2"><?php echo $r->crop_name; ?></span><br>
        <em><?php echo $r->crop_detail; ?></em><br>
        <a href="#" class="link1">Read More</a> 
      </p>
  </div>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just trying to make things more readable:

`<?php foreach($records as $r): ?>
  your codes here
<?php endforeach; ?>`